# Javascript parse array of object strings into object of objects?

Tags: javascript

I am working with a 3rd party app that requires a specific structure of data for filtering a result set. I am struggling with figuring out how to parse this out as the end result isn't a conventional array of objects.

There is a function that takes in a list of IDs from an array and turns them into object strings:

**Function:**

```
// Input for articles is an array of IDs
// articles = ['kA10W000001UK2KSAW', 'kA1d0000000DB1CCAW', 'kA1d0000000DAsOCAW']
function createExclusion(articles){
    let results = [];

    articles.forEach(element => {
        results.push(`"EqualsTo": {"Key": "sf_KnowledgeArticleId","Value": {"StringValue":"${element}"}}`)
    })

    return result;
}
```

**Input Data:**

```
let data = [
  '"EqualsTo":{"Key":"sf_KnowledgeArticleId","Value":{"StringValue":"kA10W000001UK2KSAW"}},',
  '"EqualsTo":{"Key":"sf_KnowledgeArticleId","Value":{"StringValue":"kA1d0000000DB1CCAW"}},',
  '"EqualsTo":{"Key":"sf_KnowledgeArticleId","Value":{"StringValue":"kA1d0000000DAsOCAW"}}'
]
```

**Desired End Result:**

```
{
  IndexId: 1,
  PageSize: 2,
  PageNumber: 3,
  RequestedDocumentAttributes: ["_source_uri", "sf_ArticleNumber", "sf_KnowledgeArticleId"],
  AttributeFilter: {
    "NotFilter": {
      "EqualsTo": {
        "Key": "sf_KnowledgeArticleId",
        "Value": {
          "StringValue": "kA10W000001UK2KSAW"
        }
      },
      "EqualsTo": {
        "Key": "sf_KnowledgeArticleId",
        "Value": {
          "StringValue": "kA1d0000000DB1CCAW"
        }
      },
      "EqualsTo": {
        "Key": "sf_KnowledgeArticleId",
        "Value": {
          "StringValue": "kA1d0000000DAsOCAW"
        }
      },
    },
    SortingConfiguration: {
      "DocumentAttributeKey": "_document_title",
      "SortOrder": "ASC"
    }
  };
}
```

I am trying to re-create the `AttributeFilter` data in the end result by taking the array of strings and parsing it into the correct form.

**Example:**
I was trying to get it to work with `JSON.parse()`, but the data isn't in the correct format for that.

Between either adjusting the `createExclusion` function or easily parsing it in its existing form, how can I go about turning the list of object strings into just objects as seen in the desired end result?

```
function parse(data) {
  return {
    IndexId: 1,
    PageSize: 2,
    PageNumber: 3,
    RequestedDocumentAttributes: ["_source_uri", "sf_ArticleNumber", "sf_KnowledgeArticleId"],
    AttributeFilter: {
      "NotFilter": ? // Parse data here
    },
    SortingConfiguration: {
      "DocumentAttributeKey": "_document_title",
      "SortOrder": "ASC"
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: You can't have more than one property with a given name in an object, eg "EqualsTo".  Maybe you want EqualsTo to be an array of objects.

Comment: I'm trying to find what your input is... Can you indicate clearly what an example input would be, and what the corresponding expected output should be?

Comment: Instead of `"EqualsTo": ...`, could you try wrapping it up with braces, like so - `{ "EqualsTo": ... }`? This would make the entire object which you are pushing in the "result" array a legal JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot have an object with duplicated keys in JSON:

```json
{
  "NotFilter": {
    "EqualsTo": {
      "Key": "sf_KnowledgeArticleId",
      "Value": {
        "StringValue": "kA10W000001UK2KSAW"
      }
    },
    "EqualsTo": {
      "Key": "sf_KnowledgeArticleId",
      "Value": {
        "StringValue": "kA1d0000000DB1CCAW"
      }
    },
    "EqualsTo": {
      "Key": "sf_KnowledgeArticleId",
      "Value": {
        "StringValue": "kA1d0000000DAsOCAW"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Your `NotFilter` value should be an array of objects.

---

### Parsing JSON

Your JSON should be valid, prior to calling `JSON.parse`. Make sure you remove any trailing commas and wrap each line in curly-braces.

```js
let data = [
  '"EqualsTo":{"Key":"sf_KnowledgeArticleId","Value":{"StringValue":"kA10W000001UK2KSAW"}},',
  '"EqualsTo":{"Key":"sf_KnowledgeArticleId","Value":{"StringValue":"kA1d0000000DB1CCAW"}},',
  '"EqualsTo":{"Key":"sf_KnowledgeArticleId","Value":{"StringValue":"kA1d0000000DAsOCAW"}}'
]

const parsed = data.map(item => JSON.parse(`{${item.replace(/,$/, '')}}`));

console.log(parsed);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```